# How or do we have anyway to run ValidateMetadata via REST API before creating package version

Tags: managed-package, code-coverage, metadata-api, metadata, versioning

i'd like to do a check metadata validation in advance even before creating package version in each PR.

My question is do we have any way to do check

- code-coverage
- verify metadata
  before creating package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a scratch org, then run the deployment against that org:

```
sf project deploy start -o scratch-org -w 100 --dry-run -d force-app -l RunLocalTests
```

This should give you all of the information you're likely looking for.

For a CI/CD setup, you can use pools of scratch orgs to minimize resource usage, if necessary.